# make text display on top of banner on both ie and chrome browser

Tags: html, css

I have a banner that appears in the html as the background. The image is about 900px wide and 150px high. I need html text that has about 4 links to sit on top of this banner. The issue is that it would display the links on top correctly in chrome, but in IE they were all the way down the page. Any suggestion on how to solve this issue without compromising the design idea of having the image in the background.

```css
#linkage{

margin-left:700px;
margin-top:60px;
}
#links{
height:20px;
width:280px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
color: black;

}


#bannerHead{

  background-image: url("https://placehold.it/900x200");

}
#linkid{

color: black;
}

#linkid2{

color: black;
}

#linkid3{

color: black;
}

#linkid4{

color: black;
}

a:link {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="bannerHead"><img src="" style="margin-top:0px; margin-left:660px; width:200px;"/><div id="linkage" style="margin-top:-110px;">
<a href="#" id="linkid">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" id="linkid2">About</a>&nbsp&nbsp
```

Comment: Did you notice your code snippet doesn't work?  Can you spend 5-10 minutes and at least get an image in there? You might try a service such as https://placehold.it/ which makes it very simple to add an image to your snippet.

Comment: what versions of ie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```css
#bannerHead{
  width: 900px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/900x150");
}

a:link {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="bannerHead">
    <a href="#">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">About</a>&nbsp&nbsp<a href="#">Contact</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">Info</a>
</div>
```

All I did was set a width and height for your banner div (if not its size is as big as its content, and the image does not appear completely), and include the links inside. Is this what you were trying to do?

I tested this on **Internet Explorer 6** and it works. The only issue I had was with the "placehold.it" link. I used a regular image.